# How to access the keycloak.local ingress host?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I just installed the keycloak kubernetes operator using the official OperatorHub.io guide: https://operatorhub.io/operator/keycloak-operator

Afterwards I created an operator deployment by following the official keycloak getting started guide: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-operator-kubernetes

I can see that everything works out as the needed pods, the service and the ingress are coming up and are running after a small amount of time. What I don't understand is how to access the ingress created by the deployment as the spec does not specify the normal host of my kubernetes cluster, but this instead:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: keycloak.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

That guide that I used does not specify this. What das keycloak.local mean and how do I access it?

EDIT: My keycloak config looks like this:

```
apiVersion: keycloak.org/v1alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mykeycloak
  name: mykeycloak
  namespace: test
spec:
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true
  instances: 1
status:
  credentialSecret: credential-mykeycloak
  externalURL: https://keycloak.local
  internalURL: https://keycloak.test.svc:8443
  message: ""
  phase: reconciling
  ready: true
  secondaryResources:
    ConfigMap:
    - keycloak-probes
    Deployment:
    - keycloak-postgresql
    Ingress:
    - keycloak
    PersistentVolumeClaim:
    - keycloak-postgresql-claim
    Secret:
    - credential-mykeycloak
    - keycloak-db-secret
    Service:
    - keycloak-postgresql
    - keycloak
    - keycloak-discovery
    StatefulSet:
    - keycloak
  version: 14.0.0
```

Comment: Could you provide your Keycloak config? (kubectl get keycloak <yourkeycloak>) -o yaml?

Comment: @CLNRMN There you go. As you can see, the external url is set to keycloak.local, the internal one specifies the created ClusterIP service that is not accessible from outside the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the following in your Keycloak CRD.

```
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true
```

That will create an Ingress-Object as you have already posted. By default, the Keycloak Operator is using *keycloak.local* as value for the *host*.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/olm-catalog/keycloak-operator/12.0.1/keycloaks.keycloak.org.crd.yaml#L62

So if you would like to change it to *keycloak.example.org* you have to edit your Keycloak definition to something like:

```
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true
    host: keycloak.example.org
```

Afterwards, your Ingress-Controller will listen to this Path in your request.

This should answer your first question "What das keycloak.local mean".

Your second question, "how do I access it":

I assume you have an Ingress Controller deployed on your system. If not, read up on the topic (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

If you have deployed an Ingress-Controller, you should be able to reach your Keycloak with the defined *host*.

Comment: I actually do have an ingress controller deployed which is working well for my other ingress instances. For the ingress instance to work I have to specify the ingress controllers url as the host. So I don't get why the operator even sets keycloak.local as default value instead of just aborting when not specified. It will clearly not work with the default value. I will try your recommendation of simply exchanging the host parameter - hopefully this will work.

Comment: This did in fact change the host of the ingress resource to the one of the ingress controller, but it doesn't seem to route the traffic accordingly. As I configured another ingress resources to route incoming traffic to the host's base path to another application I am redirected to that application and not my keycloak instance. Do you know how to configure path (and pathType, it was automatically set to ImplementationSpecific) for the automatically generated keycloak service instance?

Comment: I don't think the Operator can do this since the path is hardcoded and not configurable. You could try to patch it with kubectl patch or create the Ingress-Ressource by your own.

Comment: It actually worked once I patched the ingress in a way to work with the tls of my loadbalancer and removed my other ingress. Unfortunately there seems to be no way of patching the path in a way that the operator will accept. It will only work on "/".